# Can't reshape array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i want to change a image(17x15) to 2d array with code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

list = []
im = Image.open('plus1.jpg')
row,col =  im.size
print(row,col)
for i in range (row):
   for j in range (col):
        r, g, b = im.getpixel((i, j))
        list.append([r,g,b]) 
print(list)
print(len(list))
list = np.array(list)
print(list)
list.reshape(17,15)
```

It change okay to 1D array but when i using reshape to make 2D array with `list.reshape(17,15)` got the error:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

The size is 17x15, and change to 1D array have 255 elements, so why the error appear and how to make it run normaly?

Comment: Each item in list is a triplet [r, g, b]. This does not fit a numpy array representation.

Comment: what is the output of `list.shape` (which should be done after `list = np.array(list)`)?

Comment: @AngusWilliams you mean list.reshape? It reshape the array.@Aguy but i success  change to 1D array?

Comment: No, I mean `list.shape`. This will output the current shape of the array before you try to reshape it. It will hopefully give us some insight into your bug. Just add the line `print(list.shape)` beneath the line `list = np.array(list)` and report the output of the print statement.

Comment: @AngusWilliams the result of `list.shape` is `(255, 1, 3)`  255 row, 1 col and 3 elements in each item?

Comment: [shape documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html). What has happened here is that your image has 255 pixels, and you have three values at each pixel (r,g,b). So when you are trying to `reshape` your array to `(17,15)`, which suggests 255 elements, you get an error because there are actually 765 elements in `list`.

Comment: Thank you, that is error, numpy really understand `list` is 755 items array. So, have anyway to reshape `list` to an 2D array with one item include 3 elements?

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you want. I'll post an answer.

Comment: I mean reshape it to an array 17x15 with `A[i,j] = [r,g,b]` , have anyway?

Comment: I just posted an answer explaining how to do this and also what your original mistake was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is 17x15, so there are 255 pixels. For each pixel, there are three color values (r,g,b). This means that your array `list` has shape `(255,1,3)`. This means that it contains 755 elements, and an error is raised when you try to reshape it to `(17,15)`, which does not preserve the number of elements. To obtain an array that has the first two dimensions the same as your image `(17,15)`, and a third axis that contains the rgb values, you should write:

```
np.reshape(list, (17,15,3) )
```